# is it good to use std::find in c++

Tags: c++11

what is the time complexity of std::find, when the elements are large in a container(e.x. vector) in c++? Is it good to use std::find for large elements in a container, if not, then is it good to use our own version of find() - means, sort the elements and do binary search or something like that?

Comment: Do you think sorting is faster than a linear search?

Comment: The complexity is stated [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). You can beat it if the elements are sorted using [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). You can beat standard algorithms if you use special knowledge of your elements, for example by doing [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search). I can't think of any improvement based on your elements being large though, so you should probably stick to the STL until profiling reveals a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only time complexity guarantee that `std::find` makes is:

> *Complexity*: At most `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate.

Which means linear in the worst case. This does not preclude specializations for containers to offer a better complexity.

If you want to do a binary search on a sorted `std::vector`, look into [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), the complexity of `std::find` is less than n times the complexity of the comparison.

If you happen to know that the data is already sorted then you can use this knoedge about strucutre to improve the search, look at [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) for this example.

As for writing your own algorithm, while this may result in a faster program, one shouldn't optimize code unless you have a profile that says to. Also the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es1-prefer-the-standard-library-to-other-libraries-and-to-handcrafted-code) say not to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using std::find, repeatedly, for the same condition; to the point where it's a performance problem; then make a std::map with the key being the item you're searching for.  This will mean that writes have a small performance hit as they need to adjust themselves in the map; but 'finds' will be much faster.

Every container balances the advantages and disadvantages of reading and writing for some specific purpose - for example vector takes the hit for random inserts, to allow fast incremental reading and fast writing.  List takes a hit reading to allow random inserts.  If you're finding that the container isn't performing for how you're using it, then changing the container isn't unreasonable.